# repstopdf issue on Cygwin

Tags: epstopdf, cygwin

Environment: Cygwin with Cygwin Ports packages enabled for `doxygen`/`graphviz`/`mscgen`/`texlive-latex`/`texlive-latex-extras`.

Configuration: 
`doxygen` is configured to generate LaTeX output and I have PDF output via `pdflatex`. The refman.pdf is generated but is lacking some

When building this documentation, `repstopdf` is called from the build process, even though `repstopdf` has been removed from the packages.

`sh: repstopdf: command not found`

The epstopdf-sys.cfg contains something that looks like a redirection from `epstopdf` to `repstopdf`.

```
% Public domain.
% History:
% 2010/06/06 v1.2
% 2010/07/13 v1.3
% * Use `epstopdf' instead of `repstopdf' if \pdfshellescape == 1
%
\ProvidesFile{epstopdf-sys.cfg}%
  [2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live]%
\def\epstopdf@sys@cmd{repstopdf}% default is restricted epstopdf
% epstopdf-sys loads pdftexcmds, \pdf@shellescape is provided
% for LuaTeX as well
\begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
\expandafter\ifx\csname pdf@shellescape\endcsname\relax
\else
  \ifcase\pdf@shellescape
  \or
    \def\epstopdf@sys@cmd{epstopdf}% unrestricted if \pdfshellescape == 1
  \fi
\fi
\epstopdfsetup{%
  program@epstopdf=\epstopdf@sys@cmd
}%
\endinput
```

Apparently somewhere else the command line arguments are changed to use `repstopdf` args so simply changing repstopdf to epstopdf doesn't work.

Does anyone else build LaTeX docs in Cywgin with this toolchain?

Comment: On my system `repstopdf` is just a symbolic link to `epstopdf`; when the script is called as `repstopdf`, some of its features are disabled. I don't see why this link should have been removed. However, if you call `pdflatex` with the `-shell-escape` option, there should be no problem.

Comment: When I attempt that `epstopdf` simply returns it's usage text.

Comment: On Cygwin `epstopdf` is a ruby script with doesn't support the command line options that `repstopdf` does.

Comment: I don't think so; the file `epstopdf` just points to a Perl script.

Comment: Can you share the contents of that link and script or point to a location to find that content?

Comment: Which version of Cygwin are you using? I used setup.exe version 2.774 which I think is the latest cygwin.

Comment: I'm not using Cygwin; but in the TeX Live repository, in the `bin` tree, you find both [`epstopdf`](http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/bin/i386-cygwin/epstopdf?sortby=file&view=log) and [`repstopdf`](http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/bin/i386-cygwin/repstopdf?sortby=file&view=log) A Cygwin user confirmed me that they both point to the same Perl script. What does the shell command `type epstopdf` output?

Comment: $ `type epstopdf`  -bash: $'\302\203type': command not found

Comment: `$ cat /usr/bin/epstopdf`
`#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# epspdf conversion utility, main source

#####
# Copyright (C) 2006, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011 Siep Kroonenberg
# n dot s dot kroonenberg at rug dot nl
#
# This program is free software, licensed under the GNU GPL, >=2.0.
# This software comes with absolutely NO WARRANTY. Use at your own risk!
#####`

Comment: That's a *bad* `epstopdf`, I believe. TeX Live binaries usually don't reside in `/usr/bin`. Try renaming it to something else.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8818/discussion-between-emrainey-and-egreg)

Comment: I emailed the author of the ruby script epstopdf.rb and this was the response:  
"epspdf and epstopdf are two different programs with different
capabilities. [r]epstopdf is maintained and developed by @HeikoOberdiek. I wrote epspdf, now rewritten in texlua, as backend to epspdftk, which is a gui utility to do various conversions between eps, ps and pdf, in any direction." 

(@ added by me).

Comment: Probably the Ruby script should be called `epspdf` as announced in the comment and it seems to be confirmed by the author.

Comment: In any case, this is what Cygwin provides as part of the latex packages. I've installed the texlive repository directly under Cygwin and we'll see if that resolves my issues.

Comment: Did you solve your issue? If you did, please make an answer describing what was done.

Comment: Yes this did resolve the issue after installing TexLive manually. Cygwin's package was broken.

Comment: To clarify, cygwin's package was broken at worst and lacked critical functionality at best.

Comment: Can you give an answer describing what you did? Or we can close the question, if you think this won't help future readers. It's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the cygwin packages for texlive completely and manually installed TexLive from the installation instructions on their webpage, and modified the PATH to include the specific path for this package. When I ran the doxygen latex conversion, the repstopdf conversions passed without issue as the tools actually now existed.

Answer (score 1):

Install the `texlive-collection-fontutils` package using the Cygwin package manager.  It provides the `repstopdf` script.

For details of which binaries are provided by the package, see:
https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Ftexlive-collection-fontutils%2Ftexlive-collection-fontutils-20180414-1&grep=repstopdf

Comment: This was also necessary on my Debian testing.